# How to get a window handle to a COM Single-Threaded Apartment (STA)?

Tags: winapi, com

CoInitialize(NULL) creates an STA by creating a hidden window. How to get an HWND handle for this window?

Function EnumThreadWindows does not work, in an example I tried:

```
...

CoInitialize(NULL);

EnumThreadWindows(GetCurrentThreadId(), EnumThreadWndProc, 0);

...

BOOL CALLBACK EnumThreadWndProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
   m_hwnd = hwnd;

   return FALSE;
}
```

Nothing ever enters the EnumThreadWndProc.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why on Earth do you need this?  AFAIK, that window is an implementation detail and should best be left alone.

Comment: Ditto.              Don't go messing with the innards of sausage-making.

Answer (score 3):

This hidden window is Message-Only Window,  It is not visible, has no z-order, cannot be enumerated, and does not receive broadcast messages. The window simply dispatches messages.

To find message-only windows, specify HWND_MESSAGE in the hwndParent parameter of the FindWindowEx function. In addition, FindWindowEx searches message-only windows as well as top-level windows if both the hwndParent and hwndChildAfter parameters are NULL.

Source:
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599(VS.85).aspx#message_only)

Answer (score 2):

Btw, I would be *VERY* careful here - you ***really*** shouldn't be sending window messages to windows you don't own.  Your code is highly likely to break in a future version of Windows.